# Problem in MS Word figure number formatting

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, numbering

I use Microsoft Word 2007 & my figure numbers follow this style "Figure ‎1-3" I want change my style to "Figure ‎1.3"

would you please help me to do that?

Comment: you could try a Search and Replace (CTRL+H)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on any of your figures, right click and select "Insert caption". Click on "Numbering" to view the "Caption Numbering" dialog box. Change the value from `"- (hyphen)"` to `". (period)"` inside the "Use separator" box. Click OK and you're done.

[image]